# Inter-Process Comunication in C

Tags: c, process, pipe, ipc

I'am doing a exercise on IPC using pipes. The protocol is as follows:

1. client(child) reads file name from stdin
2. client sends file name over pipe to server
3. server (parent) reads file name from pipe
4. server obtains information about the file (stat sys call)
5. server sends file information over pipe to client.
6. client reads file info from pipe and outputs to stdout

I'am having problems with the last steps i don't know how to send this information correctly. At the moment output from client is garbage. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFSIZE 1024

int main()
{
    int fd1[2], fd2[2], pid, n;
    char buf[BUFSIZE];
    pipe(fd1);
    pipe(fd2);
    if ((pid = fork()) == 0)
    {
        close(fd1[0]);
        close(fd2[1]);
        read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, BUFSIZE); // 1. client(child) reads file name from stdin
        int len = strlen(buf);
        buf[len - 1] = '\0';
        write(fd1[1], buf, len); // 2. client sends file name over pipe to server
        while ((n = read(fd2[0], buf, BUFSIZE)) > 0)
        {
            write (STDOUT_FILENO, buf, n); // 6. client reads file info from pipe and outputs to stdout
        }
    }
    else
    {
        struct stat st;
        close(fd1[1]);
        close(fd2[0]);
        read(fd1[0], buf, BUFSIZE); // 3. server (parent) reads file name from pipe
        stat(buf, &st); // 4. server obtains information about the file (stat sys call)
        write(fd2[1], (void *)st.st_size, sizeof(st.st_size)); // 5. server file information over pipe to client.
        write(fd2[1], (void *)st.st_atime, sizeof(st.st_atime));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**update**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFSIZE 1024

int main()
{
    int fd1[2], fd2[2], pid;
    size_t n;
    char buf[BUFSIZE];
    pipe(fd1);
    pipe(fd2);
    if ((pid = fork()) == 0)
    {
        close(fd1[0]);
        close(fd2[1]);
        n = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, BUFSIZE - 1); // 1. client(child) reads file name from stdin
        buf[n] = '\0';
        write(fd1[1], buf, n); // 2. client sends file name over pipe to server
        while ((n = read(fd2[0], buf, BUFSIZE)) > 0)
        {
            if ((write (STDOUT_FILENO, buf, n)) != n) // 6. client reads file info from pipe and outputs to stdout
            {
                perror("client: write error\n");
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        struct stat st;
        close(fd1[1]);
        close(fd2[0]);
        read(fd1[0], buf, BUFSIZE); // 3. server (parent) reads file name from pipe
        stat(buf, &st); // 4. server obtains information about the file (stat sys call)
        if (write(fd2[1], (void *)st.st_size, sizeof(st.st_size)) != sizeof(st.st_size)) // 5. server sends file information over pipe to client
        {
            perror("server: write error\n");
        } 
        if (write(fd2[1], (void *)st.st_atime, sizeof(st.st_atime)) != sizeof (st.st_atime))
        {
            perror("server: write error\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to `dup` stdin.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `strlen()` here. You should use the return value from `read()` instead.

After `read()` the data in `buf` is nothing but a sequence of bytes, it could become a string if you add a `'\0'` byte at the end of the sequence. Since it's not present, calling `strlen()` invokes *undefined behaviour* so it doesn't matter what you do after that, it will not behave as expected.

The `strlen()` could be thought of as

```
size_t 
strlen(const char *const string)
{
    size_t length;
    length = 0;
    while (string[length] != '\0')
        ++length;
    return length;
}
```

one reason you should avoid things like

```
for (size_t i = 0 ; i < strlen(string) ; ++i) ...
```

specially because you can use a loop like the one in the `strlen()` implementation above.

Use ther return value from `read()` instead

```
ssize_t read_length;
read_length = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1);
```

if you want to make it a valid string in the sense that you can pass it to any of the `str*` functions, simply

```
buf[read_length] = '\0';
```

don't forget to check for errors `read_length != -1` for instance.

Comment: Why? There will be a '\n' from the input of user so strlen should work correctly.

Comment: No, the `'\n'` will not make `strlen()` stop.

Comment: There is no `'\0'` in the sequence of bytes received from user?

Comment: It's comming from `stdin` so I doubt there is. Also, calls to `read()` without capturing the return value are very bad.

Comment: I did some changes. There's something wrong still now i can capture the error. What's the reason for it?

Comment: From perror it's coming "Bad address" in write part of server code.